# Added a UIViewController to storyboard but can't read it programmatically in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I added a UIViewController to storyboard and tried to access it and pushed it show up, as per the code written below . But for some reasons it is being read as NULL. 
While this code works fine. I debugged both of them n i get null for `wcv` and get the value for `acv` and yes. if i check the xml code of the Storyboard file i can find the the view controller there with both it's ids **StoyboardId** and**RestorationId**

**Note :** *The same navigation code works everywhere else. I am using Xamarin-iOS (Indie license)*

```
WelcomeScreenController2 wcv =(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController ("WelcomeScreenController2") as WelcomeScreenController2;
                                        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(wcv,true);




ActivityViewController2 acv = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController ("ActivityViewController2") as ActivityViewController2;
                                        this.NavigationController.PushViewController (acv, true);
```

The difference between both of them is that `ActivityViewController2` inherits a `BaseController` while `WelcomeScreenController2` inherits `UIViewController`

**BaseController Code**

```
public partial class BaseController : UIViewController
    {
        // provide access to the sidebar controller to all inheriting controllers
        protected SidebarController SidebarController { 
            get {
                return (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).RootViewController.SidebarController;
            } 
        }

        // provide access to the sidebar controller to all inheriting controllers
        protected NavController  NavController { 
            get {
                return (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).RootViewController.NavController;
            } 
        }

        public BaseController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
        public BaseController(string nibName, NSBundle bundle) : base(nibName, bundle)
        {
        }



        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(
                new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("menu-icon")
                    , UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
                    , (sender,args) => {
                        SidebarController.ToggleMenu();
                    }), true);
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {   
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
        }

    }
```

**StoryBoardCode SS**

[image: Code from the Storyboard]

StoryBoard Code for the WelcomeScreenController2

```
<scene sceneID="684">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="685" sceneMemberID="viewController" customClass="WelcomeScreenController2" storyboardIdentifier="WelcomeScreenController2" restorationIdentifier="WelcomeScreenController2">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="686">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="687" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="4000" y="135"/>
        </scene>
```

**WelcomeScreen2 Class**

```
public partial class WelcomeScreenController2 : UIViewController
    {
        public WelcomeScreenController2 (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
}
```

**ActivityViewController2 Class**

```
public partial class ActivityViewController2 : BaseController
    {
public ActivityViewController2 (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            Title = "ACTIVITY";
        }

        public ActivityViewController2 () : base ((string)null, null)
        {
            Title = "ACTIVITY";
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the declaration of both WelcomeScreenController2 and ActivityViewController2 classes, along with their constructors?

Comment: Yes. Sure. I will do that right now.

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos Added the declarations.

Comment: Could you provide a little context for what you are doing i.e. why are you creating and pushing the UIViewControllers manually? Segues in storyboards offer a far more robust navigation experience and reduces the requirement for much boilerplate code. I appreciate there may be instances where they are not suitable (although I can not think of any off of the top of my head)

Comment: Since you have that controller in the Storyboard and the Storyboard id is correct, I can only assume that InstantiateViewController actually returns an instance, but it does not cast it to WelcomeScreenController2. Try to check if InstantiateViewController actually returns an instance, instead of null. If it does, than something goes wrong with casting it to WelcomeScreenController2. Common cases for this is outlets in the underlying object that are not found in the managed C# class.

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos I think there could have been some issue with casting but then i cleaned up and debugged/ran the app again and then it worked fine for me and is working till date. Why did it require cleanup is what I would like to know.

Comment: @HemantBavle not sure, but good to know you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't require me to change anything. Just CLEAN THE SOLUTION and DEBUG/RUN again and that worked for me.

But as @Dimitris wrote in the comment that it could have been an issue with the casting. Then why i exactly it was a messing with the new UIViewController and not the old ones and what did cleanup had to do with it , that it runs fine till date after cleanup?